# How to reproduce the results of Stanford neural parser?

Tags: stanford-nlp

I would like to run [Stanford neural dependency parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/nndep.shtml) which has very impressive performance like 92.0% UAS, 89.7% LAS (Chen & Manning, 2014). I tried to follow their instructions but got sad numbers: 66.2% UAS, 62.0% LAS. Could somebody please tell me what I did wrong?

The commands:

```
PENN_TEST_PATH="test.mrg"
CONLL_TEST_PATH="$PENN_TEST_PATH.dep"

cat penntree/23/* > $PENN_TEST_PATH  

java -cp stanford-parser-full-2014-10-31/stanford-parser.jar edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure -originalDependencies -conllx -treeFile $PENN_TEST_PATH > $CONLL_TEST_PATH
java -cp stanford-parser-full-2014-10-31/stanford-parser.jar edu.stanford.nlp.parser.nndep.DependencyParser -model stanford-parser-full-2014-10-31/PTB_Stanford_params.txt.gz -testFile $CONLL_TEST_PATH
```

Output:

```
Loading depparse model file: stanford-parser-full-2014-10-31/PTB_Stanford_params.txt.gz ...
dict=44392
pos=48
label=46
embeddingSize=50
hiddenSize=200
numTokens=48
preComputed=422468
###################
#Transitions: 91
#Labels: 45
ROOTLABEL: root
PreComputed 100000, Elapsed Time: 1.789 (s)
Initializing dependency parser done [2.6 sec].
Test File: test.mrg.dep
UAS = 66.2110
LAS = 62.0160
DependencyParser tagged 56684 words in 2416 sentences in 3.4s at 16559.7 w/s, 705.8 sent/s.
```

#### References

Chen, D., & Manning, C. (2014). A Fast and Accurate Dependency Parser using Neural Networks. In Proceedings of the 2014 Conference on Empirical Methods in Natural Language Processing (EMNLP) (pp. 740–750). Doha, Qatar: Association for Computational Linguistics.

Comment: As far as i can see in the "Models" section:

"Note that these models were trained with an earlier Matlab version of the code, and your results training with the Java code may be slightly worse". Maybe that is the case?

Comment: Did you train your own model, or is this loading the default model? If you trained your own, can you include the commands you used for training?

Comment: No, the model was extracted from `stanford-parser-3.5.0-models.jar` which comes within the same distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the problem. I need to call `edu.stanford.nlp.trees.EnglishGrammaticalStructure` with `-basic` option.